# Rollup SUM Values Not Working When Trying To Use In Bar Graph

Tags: csv, d3.js, graph, nested, rollup

I've imported data from a CSV file, managed to create a sum of "Score" column against each "Dimension" column, as well as get a distinct count of attributes under the "Dimension" column using the .map function:

```
d3.csv("TraitData.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    city: d.City,
    continent: d.Continent,
    country: d.Country,
    dimension: d.Dimension,
    identity: d.Identity,
    score: +d.Score,
    state: d.Subdivision,
    trait: d.Trait,
    index: d.Index,
    longitude: d.Latitude,
    latitude: d.Longitude
  }
}).then(function(data) {

  var varScore = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.dimension; })
    .rollup(function(v) { return {
      totalscore: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.score; }),
        }; })
    .entries(data);
  var varDimensionGroup = d3.map(data, function(d) {return d.dimension;}).keys();
  var varDimension = varDimensionGroup.length;
  var svgWidth = 1250;
  var svgHeight = 300;
  var barPadding = 5;
    var barWidth = (svgWidth/varDimension);

  console.log(varScore);
  console.log(varDimensionGroup);
  console.log(varDimension);
  console.log(svgWidth);
  console.log(svgHeight);
  console.log(barPadding);
  console.log(barWidth);

var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("#bar")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

var barChart = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(varDimensionGroup)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("height", varScore)
    .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
    .attr("transform", function (d,i) {
         var translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
         return "translate("+ translate +")";
    });
});
```

But I'm getting an error where the bar chart's height is concerned:
[image]
*Note that it says "5 errors" because my full CSV dataset has 5 Dimensions.*

Obviously the way I'm calculating the SUM of each, or the way I'm trying to utilize / reference it is wrong, but I'm not sure why. D3 is pretty new to me.

The csv file contains the following:

```
City,Continent,Country,Dimension,Identity,Score,Subdivision,Trait,Index,Latitude,Longitude
Wilmington,North America,United States,Pride,1270858,45,Delaware,Ego,1,"39,7932","-75,6181"
Wilmington,North America,United States,Humility,1270858,23,Delaware,Selflessness,2,"39,7932","-75,6181"
Wilmington,North America,United States,Humility,1270858,23,Delaware,Generosity,3,"39,7932","-75,6181"
Wilmington,North America,United States,Anger,1270858,48,Delaware,Impatience,4,"39,7932","-75,6181"
```

To summarize, what I'm trying to show is a bar chart, where the number of bars is based on the number of distinct "Dimensions" and the height of each bar is based on the sum of "Score" for each dimension.

I'm using D3.js v5.

Comment: If your div has id `bar`, as you state, then you are appending rects to a div, you need to use: `var svg = d3.select("#bar").append("svg").attr(...`

Comment: Hi Andrew, yeah I just saw that now actually. Problem is I'm now getting this error: "<rect> attribute height: Expected length, "[object Object],…"."

Obviously my varScore variable isn't working the way I want to; and I'm not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
var barChart = svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(varScore)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("height", function(d){return d.value;} )
.attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
.attr("transform", function (d,i) {
     var translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
     return "translate("+ translate +")";
```